# Why is current going towards the voltage source in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, current

[image]

You can see that Is was labeled as going towards the voltage source when doing KCL at node a. Can someone tell me why? Is it not supposed to go into the node?

Comment: The reference directions for each branch are arbitrary, but the choice will affect the signs in the summations at each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just by convention.

If you draw all the currents as either going out of a node (or into a node) a node you can say:

> The sum of all currents going out of a node are equal to 0

Obviously then some of the current will have negative values if they are infact flowing into the node, but this way you can do the maths more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's arbitrary. The three currents is, i, and Ic were chosen to go in the same direction so that they will sum to zero without worrying about signs.

You could as easily draw the arrows the other direction.

If the current is actually going in the opposite direction, then the sign of the solution will be negative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps. And you'll know this because the sign for i<sub>s</sub> will be negative. But you need to pick *some* initial direction.